# Change Secure Boot Mode EFI Variable without entering the firmware setup GUI?

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

I am trying to figure out a way to change the secure boot setting from Windows, Linux, or an EFI shell.  I assume this is impossible as that would defeat the whole purpose of secure boot, however I must ask.  So far I have investigated the EFIVARS on my PC, possibly thinking SecureBoot could be enabled by writing to either;

```
DellSecureBootMode
SecureBoot
SecureBootSetup
```

I am wondering if their is any documentation on changing such settings using `chattr`, or maybe OEM specific docs regarding EFIVARS.

I am afraid of just messing with these, and I am guessing they won't work anyway.

Comment: What have you searched for or researched? Do you understand the principles behind how SecureBoot works? Do you know what could happen if you enable it at this time? Will your system still boot, or will it be unable to find a properly signed bootloader to execute?

Comment: Yes I understand that EFI binaries must be signed, as well as the kernel and kernel modules.  I am wondering about what is written to the motherboard enabling/disabling this check at boot.  Ex. for some EFI settings there is a NVRAM entry.

Comment: I haven't heard of runtime possibility of even enabling SB; you might still find rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders helpful for many tangential questions (I'm thankful to Rod as his guides have helped me implementing UEFI in ALT Linux, you see :-).

Comment: @Jack1221: First, edit your main question to give details about things others' here ask in comments. Second, my point is mainly... I do not see much evidence of you having done much reading or research. For one, `chattr` has nothing to do with what you are asking. Likewise, you cannot change SecureBoot on/off so casually. That is handled by the BIOS, before it even gets to a bootloader or operating system. Your initial presumption is correct; being able to change it so casually would defeat the purpose of it.